# Error trying to put array into neural network

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, tensorflow

im trying to use a neural network on an extremely simple custom dataset.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from sklearn import datasets

X = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]])

Y = np.array([[0],
              [1],
              [1],
              [0]])

Xtest = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
                  [0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1],
                  [0, 1, 1]])

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 4, 3])
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, dropout=0.5)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='sigmoid')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_square')
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=3)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=1, show_metric=True,
          batch_size=32, snapshot_step=100)
```

But im getting the following error:

`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (4, 3) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 4, 3)`'

Can someone help me fix this and explain to me exactly what it means??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape you specified is (None, 4, 3). As documented [here](http://tflearn.org/layers/core/):

> shape: list of int. An array or tuple representing input data shape.
>   It is required if no placeholder is provided. First element should be
>   'None' (representing batch size), if not provided, it will be added
>   automatically.

So `None` is batch size that could be dynamic (TF reads it step by step more or less) - NN doesn't care about its length as it doesn't affect its architecture. `3` needed just to (usually) create 3 input neurons for your network. Note that you can't expand dimensionality dynamically - aka pass 4 dimensional data-point into network with shape (?, 3).

Your input is:

```
X = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
          [0, 1, 1],
          [1, 0, 1],
          [1, 1, 1]])
```

Which I suppose is a batch with four 3-dimensional data-points. There is no need to specify batch size (count of data-points) for TensorFlow, so you just need:

```
 net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3])
```

Or simply speaking `?` in your error message could be anything (it's actually 4 for your sample. So your `(4,3)` array fits into `(?,3)` shape.

---

As of "AssertionError: Input dim should be at least 3" the solution from [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/283):

```
X = np.array([[[0, 0, 1]],
          [[0, 1, 1]],
          [[1, 0, 1]],
          [[1, 1, 1]]])

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 1, 3])
```

Basically some NN architectures require sample array (not data-point!) to be 3 dimensional (so data data-point's shape has to be something like `1 x 3`). The expansion is pretty straitforward. You could also do `shape=[None, 3, 1]` and wrap individual components.

Comment: So i ignore the 4? if i have lets say a shape of (214215, 3) as opposed to (4,3) net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3]) remains the same answer??

Comment: @Mark yes. TensorFlow will read your array iteratively, step by step. They need shape just in order to create appropriate neural network. In your case 3 neurons on the input.

Comment: Ok great thanks a lot dk14 im getting the error: AssertionError: Input dim should be at least 3, can you please explain this? i really know i should read the doc but i find it really helpful talking to others

Comment: I think this will help: https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/283

Comment: @Mark I updated the answer

Comment: Ok so i fixed the input now im getting this error: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (4, 1) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Comment: @Mark `tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='sigmoid')` basically says that you'll get output shaped (?, 2), but the shape of your Y is (4, 1) - so adjust your Y to be (?, 2) specifically (4,2) like [[1,0], [1,1], [0,1], [1,1]])

Comment: or `tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='sigmoid')`